# How I can Replace main() in already-compiled application?

Tags: linux, dynamic

I need additional initialization over existing in dynamic-linked application.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I can almost guarantee you that this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Try to play with LD_PRELOAD. I'm too tired now to make it work, but hopefully it can solve your problem. Be aware of the point that Lutz presents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hook additional code before running `main()` in an already-compiled program, you can use a combination of the `constructor` attribute, and `LD_PRELOAD` like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__((constructor)) init() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -shared demo_print.c -o demo_print.so -fPIC  
$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/demo_print.so true             
Hello, world!
```

If you don't want to run normal `main()` at all, just terminate (with `exit()` etc) before `main()` runs. Note that you won't be able to actually get the address of `main()` to call manually - just return from your constructor to continue normal startup.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a shared library that needs specific startup initialisation, you can use the GCC "constructor" extension:

```
void foo() __attribute__ ((constructor))
```